# Aggregate routes with a certain item ORTools

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm wondering if it is possible aggregate routes with a certain item, using ORTools VRPTWs problem.

For example imagine I have several orders, in which some of them are specials resulting in the following nodes:

```
{A, B, C, D, E} -> common  
{F, G, H} -> special
```

Therefore using a naive solution would be:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E  
F -> G -> H
```

Since the special nodes were aggregated together.

But, in my case, I want to set a penalty for which violation
Where one possible solution would be:

```
A -> F -> B -> G (two special nodes here)  
C -> D  (only common)  
H -> E (special node here)
```

Notice that the solver tried to group together the special nodes.

How can I achieve such behaviour using ORTools?

Answer (score 0):

In order to force the model to put certain orders into same the same vehicle, you can use the readily available `AddSoftSameVehicleConstraint`. The implementation of this method can be seen [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.cc#L1529).

According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L857C8-L857C36) this method, 
"Adds a soft constraint to force a set of variable indices to be on the
same vehicle. If all nodes are not on the same vehicle, each extra vehicle
used adds 'cost' to the cost function."

One way you could use this in python is as follows (You can work out similar implementations for different languages):

```
routing.AddSoftSameVehicleConstraint([1, 2, 3, 4], 100)
```

which translates to, if `VehicleVar(...)` of nodes `[1, 2, 3, 4]` are not the same, 100 cost will be added to objective value for each vehicle used more than one.